# Complex power and another from of complex power

Tags: power, analysis

I am a little confused with something, when we have complex power in a form  S = U * I. There is also version of S = (1/2) * U * I. So I would like to know what is the difference between those two power formulas and how do I know which one to use? Thanks.

Comment: Please link to where your read these two formulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AC voltages are currents are commonly given as rms or root-mean-square values. They are less commonly given in peak values. These are related by a factor of \$\sqrt{2}\$

$$V_{peak} = \sqrt{2}V_{rms}$$

$$I_{peak} = \sqrt{2}I_{rms}$$

When calculating (apparent) power, we multiply the rms values of voltage and current.

$$S = I_{rms}V_{rms}$$

But this is the same as

$$S = \frac{I_{peak}}{\sqrt{2}}\frac{V_{peak}}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{I_{peak}V_{peak}}{2}$$

Note that \$S\$ is the symbol for apparent power, but it is also the symbol for complex power. However, in the equation for complex power, we do not simply multiply \$V\$ times \$I\$, but take the complex conjugate of the current. Thus in the complex case,

$$S = V_{rms}I_{rms}^* = \frac{V_{peak}I_{peak}^*}{2}$$

where \$I^*\$ means the complex conjugate of \$I\$.

Comment: Thank you, so it is same if I understood it correctly?

Comment: Yes, the power is the same, and the current and voltage, although represented by different numbers are actually the same as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! You have really helped me.